# matplotlib axis auto scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to rewrite a MatLab script to work in python. The scaling of the plot doesn't happen automatically like in MatLab. Code below, so I know how to scale it my self but I just want it autoscaled like in Matlab. How to do this? The whole data set is much larger, but for now, I am only interested in one part.[Whole data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86b2K.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
filename1 = ("1_quartz_IR7_8s.csv")
dataquartz = pd.read_csv(filename1, header = None)
print(dataquartz.head())

filename2 = ("2_water_600s_IR7.csv")
datawater = pd.read_csv(filename2, header = None)
print(datawater.head())

norm = (datawater[1]-850)/dataquartz[1]
wavenumber = (1/datawater[0]-1/793.3)*10**7

plt.plot(wavenumber,norm)
plt.title("Python Script Test")
plt.xlabel("Wavenumber [1/cm]")
plt.ylabel("Intensity")
plt.xlim(1400,1850)
plt.grid("True")
plt.show()
```

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0I2W.png)

Comment: matplotlib plots *do* scale automatically. But here you set the limits manually, so it will stick to those limits.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified it better. Now entered some more data, could you answer again please?

Comment: Could you clarify what you don't like in your plot, and what you want at the end ?

Comment: So the small peak has to be more visible in the plot, this is essential for the graph.

Comment: Would a logarithmic scale help? `plt.yscale("log")`.

Comment: Kind of, but now really what I was going for...

Comment: It's more of a data visualization problem than a coding/matplotlib problem really. If you want the 1700 cm^-1 peak to be visible despite the others peaks that are 10 times bigger around it, typically we'd use a log scale. What were you going for? `plt.ylim(0, 0.15)` and hide the top of the other peaks?